# Brunch builds but "Cannot find module 'buffer'" on open

Tags: javascript, build, brunch

We are attempting to transition our front end build to use Brunch. Here's the Brunch configuration I have so far:

```
module.exports = {

  files: {
    javascripts: {
      joinTo: {
        'vendor.js': /^(?!source)/,
        'app.js': /^source/
      },
      entryPoints: {
        'source/scripts/app.jsx': 'app.js'
      }
    },
    stylesheets: {joinTo: 'core.css'},
  },

  paths: {
    watched: ['source']
  },

  modules: {
    autoRequire: {
      'app.js': ['source/scripts/app']
    }
  },

  plugins: {
    babel: {presets: ['latest', 'react']},
    postcss: {processors: [require('autoprefixer')]},
    assetsmanager: {
      copyTo: {
        'assets': ['source/resources/*']
      }
    },
    static: {
      processors: [
        require('html-brunch-static')({
          processors: [
            require('pug-brunch-static')({
              fileMatch: 'source/views/home.pug',
              fileTransform: (filename) => {
                filename = filename.replace(/\.pug$/, '.html');
                filename = filename.replace('views/', '');
                return filename;
              }
            })
          ]
        })
      ]
    }

  }

};
```

I added the `modules.autoRequire` section to the Brunch configuration and then the following error started happening. Without `modules.autoRequire` I have no console error but also my web app does not start. Running `brunch build` results in no errors, but when I open the built website, I get the error

> Uncaught Error: Cannot find module 'buffer' from 'lodash/lodash.js'

The first line in the stacktrace points me to this function in vendor.js

```
var require = function(name, loaderPath) {
  if (loaderPath == null) loaderPath = '/';
  var path = expandAlias(name);

  if (has.call(cache, path)) return cache[path].exports;
  if (has.call(modules, path)) return initModule(path, modules[path]);

  throw new Error("Cannot find module '" + name + "' from '" + loaderPath + "'");
};
```

I'm not sure how to proceed to get my build working. This [issue](https://github.com/brunch/brunch/issues/1293) seems like it may be relevant.

How can I overcome this error? (Please feel free to ask for additional information. I'm not sure what all would be helpful.)

Comment: What is your `package.json`?

Comment: @JohannesFilter Thanks to your comment I stripped unnecessary packages from my `package.json` and now it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Brunch takes the steps of the build pipeline from the (brunch specific) npm packages defined in the `package.json`. Therefore makes sure to include all the needed packages (or to remove unnecessary ones).

See the [docs for more information about how to use plugins](http://brunch.io/docs/using-plugins).

Answer (score 0):

you need to upgrade the version of node to 16 or above.
you can run the command below if you are on Mac OS.

> brew update && brew upgrade node && npm install -g npm